# How to make a Sublime Text snippet work with Emmet installed

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I am trying to make a snippet in Sublime Text 3 that only applies to CSS files. This is the snippet I have:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[/*
Theme Name: ${1:Theme name here and so on...}
Theme URI: 
Author: 
Author URI: 
Description: 
Version: 1.0.0
License: 
License URI: 
Text Domain: 
Tags: 
*/]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>xyz</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

The problem is if I open a CSS file, type `xyz` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> all I will get is `xyz: ;`. So it seems as if Sublime Text has already assigned the <kbd>tab</kbd> to insert `: ;` instead of my snippet.

This problem does not occur if I remove the plugin package [Emmet](http://emmet.io/).

How can I get this snippet to work?

Comment: are you using a third party CSS syntax / package? this seems to work on a vanilla ST3 install. (Tested on build 3125)

Comment: Yes, just realised it seems if I remove Emmet it works. But I would really like to use Emmet though.

Comment: looking at https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler, try setting `"disabled_single_snippet_for_scopes": "source.css"` in your Emmet preferences

Comment: @KeithHall make that an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at http://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler, suggests that it should be possible to get snippets to work in CSS files with Emmet enabled by adding the following preference in your Emmet preferences file:

```
"disabled_single_snippet_for_scopes": "source.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Emmet, consider using an [Emmet snippet](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) instead.

```
{
    "css": {
        "filters": "css",
        "profile": "css",
        "snippets": {
            "xyz": "/*\nTheme Name: ${1:Theme name here and so on...}\nTheme URI: \nAuthor: \nAuthor URI: \nDescription: \nVersion: 1.0.0\nLicense: \nLicense URI: \nText Domain: \nTags: \n*/"
        }
    }
}
```