# What is wrong with my CSS snippet for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-snippets

My snippet's code is :

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/* === ${1:Comment} ==== */
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cssCom</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.css</scope>
</snippet>
```

When I use the tabTrigger, `cssCom` Emmet takes control and turns it into:

```
cssCom: ;
```

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with the CSS snippet code?

Comment: it works for me - did you save it in the `Packages/User` folder as a `.sublime-snippet` file? and are you trying it with the default CSS syntax highlighting enabled on your file?

Comment: Yes I have done all that. Note that I have emmet, and when I press the tab key, the text turns to `cssCom: ;` instead of inserting my snippet. (Updating question to show this also).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Sublime Text snippet work with Emmet installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181441/how-to-make-a-sublime-text-snippet-work-with-emmet-installed)

Comment: @KeithHall Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: not necessary, I think - duplicates can help other people find the solution to their problem